# Logitech Steering Wheel G29 unable to get Input button pressed in Unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I am building drive game using Unity. I have create a new MonoBehaviour:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace DrivingTest
{
    public class FearTest : MonoBehaviour
    {
        //public GameObject redDot;
        //public TextMeshPro textAnsia2;
        //public TextMesh textAnsia3;
        public GameObject text;

        public int shouldFearTest = 0; // 0 - false, 1 - true

        public int secondsInterval;

        //public int secondsToDisaply;
        public int reactionTestDuration;

        private float endTime;
        private float dotDisaplyAtTime;
        private List<float> dotDisplayReactTime = new List<float>();
        private int missedSignals;

        private int currentDotsCount;
        private bool isReactionAlreadyGiven;

        public bool ShouldFearTest
        {
            get { return shouldFearTest != 0; }
        }

        void OnEnable()
        {
            GameManager.TestSceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            GameManager.TestSceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
        }

        #region Scene Loaded

        private void OnSceneLoaded(eTESTS test)
        {
            if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name != test.ToString())
                return;

            Reset();
            GetApiParams();
        }

        public void Disabler()
        {
            //qui posso recuperare il valore del ansia selezionata.
            //text.SetActive(false);
        }

        #endregion

        private void GetApiParams()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (!GameManager.Instance)
            {
                Init();
                return;
            }
#endif
            Debug.Log("called fearTest");
            NextTestOutput nextTestOutput = GameManager.Instance.currentTest;
            if (nextTestOutput.content != null && nextTestOutput.content.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in nextTestOutput.content[0].listInputParameter)
                {
                    switch ((ePARAMETERS) item.id)
                    {
                        case ePARAMETERS.FEAR:
                            shouldFearTest = System.Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                            break;

                        case ePARAMETERS.DURATION_OF_TEST:
                            reactionTestDuration = System.Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                            break;

                        case ePARAMETERS.REPEAT_FEAR:
                            secondsInterval = System.Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                Debug.Log("called rt " + ShouldFearTest);
                if (ShouldFearTest)
                {
                    Init();
                }
            }
        }

        Coroutine displayCoroutine;

        public void Init()
        {
            endTime = Time.time + reactionTestDuration + 10;
            SetRedDotSize();
            displayCoroutine = StartCoroutine(RedDotDisplay());
        }

        private IEnumerator RedDotDisplay()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

            while (true)
            {
                SetRandomDotPosition();
                RedDot(true);
                isReactionAlreadyGiven = false;
                dotDisaplyAtTime = Time.time;
                currentDotsCount++;
                //yield return new WaitForSeconds(secondsToDisaply);

                if (!isReactionAlreadyGiven)
                {
                    missedSignals++;
                }

                //RedDot(false);
                if ((reactionTestDuration > 0 && endTime <= Time.time))
                    break;

                float waitTime = secondsInterval; // - secondsToDisaply;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
            }
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (!ShouldFearTest)
                return;
            LogitechGSDK.LogiUpdate();
            Debug.Log("Volante collegato: " + LogitechGSDK.LogiIsConnected(0) + " " + LogitechGSDK.LogiUpdate());
            for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
            {
                if (LogitechGSDK.LogiButtonIsPressed(0, i))
                    Debug.Log("Pulsante " + i + " premuto: " + LogitechGSDK.LogiButtonIsPressed(0, i));
            }

            if (!isReactionAlreadyGiven && text.activeSelf && (LogitechGSDK.LogiUpdate() &&
                                                               LogitechGSDK.LogiIsConnected(0) &&
                                                               LogitechGSDK.LogiButtonIsPressed(0, 23)))
            {
                isReactionAlreadyGiven = true;
                float reactionTime = Time.time - dotDisaplyAtTime;
                Debug.Log("Reaction Time RT : " + reactionTime);
                RedDot(false);
                dotDisplayReactTime.Add(reactionTime);
            }
        }

        public double GetReactionTimeAvg()
        {
            double avg = 0;
            foreach (var item in dotDisplayReactTime)
            {
                avg += item;
            }

            //avg / currentDotsCount
            return avg / (float) dotDisplayReactTime.Count;
        }

        public double GetMissedSignals()
        {
            return ((float) missedSignals / (float) currentDotsCount) * 100;
        }

        private void RedDot(bool state)
        {
            //redDot.SetActive(state);
            text.SetActive(state);
        }

        private void SetRedDotSize()
        {
            //redDot.transform.localScale *= dotRadius;
            //textAnsia2.transform.localScale *= dotRadius;
            //textAnsia3.transform.localScale *= dotRadius;
        }

        private void SetRandomDotPosition()
        {
            Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3(500, 500, 0);
            Debug.Log("text ansia 2 : " + pos2);
            text.transform.position = pos2;
            //text.transform.position = pos;
        }

        #region Getting Red Dot b/w 2 cricles

        /*
         Code from : https://gist.github.com/Ashwinning/89fa09b3aa3de4fd72c946a874b77658
        */

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a random point in the space between two concentric circles.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="minRadius"></param>
        /// <param name="maxRadius"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        Vector3 GetRandomPointBetweenTwoCircles(float minRadius, float maxRadius)
        {
            //Get a point on a unit circle (radius = 1) by normalizing a random point inside unit circle.
            Vector3 randomUnitPoint = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized;
            //Now get a random point between the corresponding points on both the circles
            return GetRandomVector3Between(randomUnitPoint * minRadius, randomUnitPoint * maxRadius);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a random vector3 between min and max. (Inclusive)
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The <see cref="UnityEngine.Vector3"/>.</returns>
        /// <param name="min">Minimum.</param>
        /// <param name="max">Max.</param>
        Vector3 GetRandomVector3Between(Vector3 min, Vector3 max)
        {
            return min + Random.Range(0, 1) * (max - min);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Reset

        private void Reset()
        {
            if (displayCoroutine != null)
                StopCoroutine(displayCoroutine);

            RedDot(false);
            shouldFearTest = 0;
            reactionTestDuration = 0;
            secondsInterval = 0;
            missedSignals = 0;
            endTime = 0;
            dotDisaplyAtTime = 0;
            dotDisplayReactTime.Clear();
            //redDot.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            //textAnsia2.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            //textAnsia3.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            currentDotsCount = 0;
            isReactionAlreadyGiven = true;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

With this class I am able to display my input when game is still running, but I need to get Logitech steering wheel input. In particular when the user uses the buttons 22 - 23 - 24.

So I write this code:

```cs
LogitechGSDK.LogiIsConnected(0) && LogitechGSDK.LogiButtonIsPressed(0, 23)
```

but the method LogiIsConnected(0) is false every time and I am not able to listen if some buttons are pressed or not pressed. But if I use it to turn car, run, break car - it works.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Do not receive any key at this time? Will you get any returns if you remove the `LogiTech.IsConnected`?

Comment: No number changes, that is? There is a simple YouTube link here that simply gets the numbers, doesn't it? (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nbeRGfofGk)

Comment: I try to follow the youtube video but if I try to set on MainCamera LogitechSteeringWheel I can display on screen the message: PLEASE PLUG IN A STEERING WHEEL OR A FORCE FEEDBACK CONTROLLER
but the steering whell is connect on my pc by USB cable and I m able to drive a care with him